# combine two queries using CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have two queries

Query 1 : Retrieves last two end of month date from Date Dimension output as

```
ActualDate
28-02-2019
30-01-2019
```

Query 2 : Uses a Date field in a where clause...

```
E.g. All the data at Date D1.
```

How can I  use the output of query 1 recursively in query 2 so that

The combined output should be

```
All Data at Date "28-02-2019" Unionall 
All Data at Date "30-01-2019"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Simply saying, the query 2 is as below and I want to get the results for this query for last 3 months by recursive CTE by changing the actual date

```
select     SL.InvoiceID, 
           sum(SL.Balance) as Balance,

    from FactableBalance as SL
    inner join DateDimension as DT1 
       on DT1.ActualDate = '2019-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    where SL.LedgerAccountType = 'Credit'
      and DT1.ID >= BalanceOpenDateID
      and DT1.ID < BalanceCloseDateID 
    group by SL.InvoiceID
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
   with cte1
    as
    (select * from query1
    ), cte2 as
    (
    select * from query2
    ) select * from cte1 union all
    select * from cte2
```

Comment: but where can I join query 1 and query 2 on date field?

Comment: @Sachy123 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6856bf930f24a1971834aa2e6c496528 this is the fiddle link you can create your query i can help to you for formating

Comment: so the first query gives all the dates, and second query is something like this   
     Select * from sometable where Datefield = <one of the date from query 1>

Comment: So in your example. I cannot write select * from query2. But i can only write select * from query2 where date =

Comment: you can add where filter no problem it is more better if create a fiddle

Comment: How ? Can I write select * from query2 where dateid=cte1.dateid

Comment: @Sachy123 sahare you actual problem on question description otherwise its tough to understand what you need and i think the two answer for this question given you the clear idea about your problem if you have new problem then ask please in separate question

Comment: Due to security reasons i cant post the actual query. But i will try to more expand my question soon.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Comment: Here is the query!

Comment: select     SL.InvoiceID, 
           sum(SL.BalanceSAC) as SalesLedgerSAC,
         
    from FactableBalance as SL
    inner join DateDimension as DT1 
       on DT1.ActualDate = '2019-02-28 00:00:00.000'
    where SL.LedgerAccountType = 'Credit'
      and DT1.ID >= BalanceOpenDateID
      and DT1.ID < BalanceCloseDateID 
    group by SL.InvoiceID

Comment: @Sachy123 what will i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
with dates as (
      . . .
     )
select . . .
from dates left join
     <something goes here> s
     on s.<whatever> ? d.date
```

It is a little vague, but you can use `join` to "fill in" the comparison you are looking for.